# Doctrine Querybuilder issues in symfony2. Usage questions

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

Using doctrine for the first time in a project, and I'm having a few issues with the query builder.

First up, in a controller I used the following:

```
$conn = $this->get('database_connection');
$users = $conn->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM Users');
```

This worked fine and returns an array of users from my DB.

I then tried to use the query builder to fetch the forenames of all users. By looking at examples i found the following:

```
$conn = $this->get('database_connection');
$qb = $conn->createQueryBuilder();
    
$qb->select("forename")
   ->from("Users", "u")
   ->where("u.id = :user_id")
   ->setParameter('user_id', 1);
    
   $query = $qb->getQuery();
   $results = $query->getResults();
```

I get told that the gDoctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder::getQuery() method is not defined, which I found odd as almost all the examples I found use it.

I did a search and found [Doctrine documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.1/doctrine/dbal/query/querybuilder.html#execute%28%29) but I'm now confused how to use it at all.

Would someone be kind enough to give me an example of how to use the above to retrieve the forename for the User with id 1. I'm sure that once I have a simple example that work I will be fine from there.

Thanks!

Now Resolved:
After looking at the Documentation (and with help from others), I found the general layout for the queryBuilder is as follows:

```
$conn = $this->get('database_connection');
$qb = $conn->createQueryBuilder();

$stmt = $qb->select("forename")
   ->from("Users", "u")
   ->where("u.id = :user_id")
   ->setParameter('user_id', 1)
   ->execute();
       
$userNames = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

The general idea being that the execute method returns a Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Statement, with the parameters set as specified. From this statement you can call one of the various method stated [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.1/index.html) to get the results from the DB.

Hope this helps someone else who is having problems!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confused slightly by the documents on doctrine and using it with symfony.  From the error message you are getting a DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder.  There is not a method getQuery for that object.  You should be able to use the execute method to get the results you want.

Now with that being said the way I would do it is through either a repository class for the Users entity, or I would do

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
```

then do what you were doing before...

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I think I had Zend_Db on the brain and was half expecting this to behave the same way. The implementation you mention above is very much related to the ORM side of Doctrine (which I'm playing with in another project). However with this project, all models and mappers are in place, so I just wanted to use the DBAL. It seemed odd to me to reference an entity manager when I had no entities (in the Doctrine sense), so just wanted to use it via the DB connection. Just personal preference. I go there in the end though (see edited question). Thanks!